# Validar si existe datos en un campo de una tabla

Tags: sql, oracle

Me encuentro haciendo un reporte en SQL y necesito validar si existe registro en un campo de una tabla.

La consulta que estoy utilizando en mi reporte es la siguiente

```
(SELECT SPRCMNT_TEXT_NAR
        FROM SPRCMNT
        WHERE SPRCMNT_PIDM = SHRDGMR_PIDM
        AND SPRCMNT_CMTT_CODE = '15'
        AND SPRCMNT_ORIG_CODE = 'FTDF') FILEXML
```

El campo en donde debo validar si existe información es en `SPRCMNT_TEXT_NAR` si no existe información en ese campo no debería mostrármelo en el reporte.

Comment: ¿Y la pregunta cuál es?

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar el operador IS NOT NULL en tu where

```
SELECT column_names
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IS NOT NULL;
```